# NameError: name 'openTokenWindow' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter, button

In the code I have two GUI pages, the first is Home.py and the second is TokenRoom.py. When I press a button to open TokenRoom from Home I get this:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\valer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\valer\PycharmProjects\thesis\GUI\Home.py", line 41, in <lambda>
    loginButton.config(command= lambda : openTokenWindow(root))
NameError: name 'openTokenWindow' is not defined
```

This is the button code in Home:

```
#Login Button
imgLoginButton = Image.open('Images/door.png')
imgLoginButton = imgLoginButton.resize((60,60))
photoLogin = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgLoginButton)

loginButton = tk.Button(root)
loginButton.config(command= lambda : openTokenWindow(root))
loginButton.config(font=('Ink Free',20,'bold'))
loginButton.config(bg="#ff6200")
loginButton.config(fg='#fffb1f')
loginButton.config(activebackground='#FF0000')
loginButton.config(activeforeground='#fffb1f')
loginButton.config(borderwidth=8)
loginButton.config(image=photoLogin)
loginButton.config(compound='left')
loginButton.place(x=900,y=15)
```

This is the file TokenRoom:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


from PIL import Image,ImageTk

from GUI.Home import setHome


def openTokenWindow(window):

    def backHome():
        tokenWindow.destroy()
        setHome()
    window.destroy()


    #tokenWindow settings
    tokenWindow = tk.Tk()
    tokenWindow.title("ELSA")
    tokenWindow.resizable(0, 0)
    tokenWindow.geometry("1100x600")




    # Back Button
    imgBacktButton = Image.open('Images/back.png')
    imgBacktButton = imgBacktButton.resize((60, 60))
    photoBack = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgBacktButton)

    backButton = tk.Button(tokenWindow)
    backButton.config(command= lambda : backHome())
    backButton.config(font=('Ink Free', 20, 'bold'))
    backButton.config(bg="#fffb1f")
    backButton.config(fg='#fffb1f')
    backButton.config(activebackground='white')
    backButton.config(activeforeground='#fffb1f')
    backButton.config(borderwidth=8)
    backButton.config(image=photoBack)
    backButton.config(compound='left')
    backButton.place(x=80, y=480)




    # mainloop, runs infinitely
    tokenWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: Well, did you import TokenRoom in Home?

Comment: I used this code to import TokenRoom in Home: from GUI.TokenRoom import *

Comment: Put all imgLoginButton  before # mainloop, runs infinitely

Comment: all buttons are before mainloop

Comment: Yes. That will do your job.

Answer (score 0):

I solved. I put "import GUI.TokenRoom import openTokenWindow" into the function. It's named 'locally import'. But the proble now is another: I have to press twice time the Exit button to exit. It's so weird. I don't know why